# Get loaded module from another process

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct, process, inject

I want to get all modules from another process. But it returns absurd values. Program stay in do-while loop for one time. After that exits from do-while loop.

I can't find where is the mistake - how can I fix this? I know that program must be in do-while loop for several time but it don't.

```
NTSTATUS Status;
PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
ULONG ReturnLength;
Status = NtQueryInformationProcess(
    INJECTOR_INFO.process.processHandle,
    ProcessBasicInformation,
    &pbi,
    sizeof(PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION),
    &ReturnLength);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
    printf("NtQueryInformationProcess failed.(pbi)\n");
    return;
}
else {
    PLIST_ENTRY  HeadEntry = pbi.PebBaseAddress->LoaderData->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
    PLIST_ENTRY nextEntry = pbi.PebBaseAddress->LoaderData->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Blink;


    DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
    PLDR_MODULE pLdrModule = nullptr;
    LDR_MODULE LdrModule;
    do
    {
        LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY LdrEntry;
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY Base = CONTAINING_RECORD(HeadEntry, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);

        if (NT_SUCCESS(Status = NtReadVirtualMemory(INJECTOR_INFO.process.processHandle, Base, &LdrEntry, sizeof(LdrEntry), &dwBytesRead)))
        {
            if (dwBytesRead != sizeof(LdrEntry)) {
                printf("length doesn't match");
                return;
            }
            char* pLdrModuleOffset = reinterpret_cast<char*>(HeadEntry) - sizeof(LIST_ENTRY);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status = NtReadVirtualMemory(INJECTOR_INFO.process.processHandle, pLdrModuleOffset, &pLdrModule, sizeof(pLdrModule), &dwBytesRead))) { 
                printf("pLdrModuleOffset doesn't read"); return;
            }else if (dwBytesRead != sizeof(pLdrModule)) { printf("pLdrModule length doesn't match"); return; }
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status = NtReadVirtualMemory(INJECTOR_INFO.process.processHandle, pLdrModule, &LdrModule, sizeof(LdrModule), &dwBytesRead))) { 
                printf("pLdrModule doesn't read"); return;
            }else if (dwBytesRead != sizeof(LdrModule)) { printf("LdrModule length doesn't match"); return; }

            if (LdrEntry.DllBase)
            {
                printf("BaseAddress:     %p\n", LdrModule.BaseAddress);
                printf("Reference Count: %d\n", LdrModule.LoadCount);
            }

            HeadEntry = LdrEntry.InMemoryOrderLinks.Flink;
        }
        else { printf("LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY doesn't read"); return; }
    } while (HeadEntry != nextEntry);
}
```

I put breakpoint on `!NT_SUCCESS(Status)` after NtQueryInformationProcess for values of variables:

[Values after NtQueryInformationProcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktgDf.png)

Another breakpoint for values of variables in do while for the end of the first cycle:

[Values for the end of the first cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWGHV.png)

Comment: Anything wrong with [EnumProcessModules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You are querying a remote process for it's `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION`, but then you proceed to follow the pointers in your own process:

`PLIST_ENTRY  HeadEntry = pbi.PebBaseAddress->LoaderData->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;`

For this to work, read the `PEB` from the remote process (from `pbi.PebBaseAddress`),
then read the `LoaderData` from the remote process (`PEB.LoaderData`).
Then, follow the `InMemoryOrderModuleList` (again, read the data from the remote process).

At this point you can iterate over the entire list, by reading each entry from the remote process.